# Dynamic VLookup and Sum composition finder with Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I’m currently looking for two formulas in order to gain in efficiency. Let me develop my research.

Firstly I’m looking for a “sum composition finder”. Basically let imagine I have 5 figures and a sixth which is the sum of x of those figures.

I’m looking for a formula which could find what the figures that compose my sum are.

Here’s an example: 
1)  54
2)  21
3)  20
4)  47
5)  62
Sum : 41

Here I’ve got a sum of 41 thus I want the formula to be able to find 21 and 20 which make 41. Does someone have any idea about how I could make this works ?

Secondly I’m looking for a dynamic vlookup. As you may know vlookup use an index number to take the value needed. My plan is to make a vlookup based on the name of the column thus if there is any change in the table (I.e if I’m adding a column on my table) my vlookup isn’t broken. Also I want to know if it is possible to fix a dynamic table area.

For instance if my table goes from column A to E I would like that my vlookup is able to extend to F when I’ll add a column by himself.

I hope I’ve been clear enough, feel free to ask for some more information if something isn’t clear.

Thank in advance !

Comment: If you have any .NET experience I would take a look at Excel-DNA. The first function should be trivial to write, the second may be more work (find column name dynamically and then do vLookup).

Answer (score 1):

You can choose the column to retrieve in a `VLOOKUP` by applying a `MATCH` function against the column headers.

[image]

The formula in I2 is `=VLOOKUP($G2,$A$2:$Z$99,MATCH($H2,$A$1:$Z$1,0),FALSE)`.

Another method is using `INDEX` against the data grid, applying `MATCH` to both the *row_number* and *column_number* parameters. In the above case, this would be `=INDEX($B$2:$Z$99,MATCH($G2,$A$2:$A$99,0),MATCH($H2,$B$1:$Z$1,0))`. Of course, you would have to get the formulas out of the way of the expansion area in order that you do not receive circular references.

*Addendum:* I've modified the formulas originally supplied to demonstrate expandability.